# Running a python module for fixed time from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pyserial

Was using the below command from terminal to read the serial output -

```
python -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/cu.usbmodem1431 9600
```

The above provides me the correct response. I wished to run this for exactly 10 seconds. 
Hence I tried the following -

```
(python -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/cu.usbmodem1431 9600) & sleep 10 ; kill $!
```

However, I don't receive any output from this while the command runs for 10 seconds. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for the lack of understanding over the same.

Comment: Was not able to reproduce it. Maybe it's an issue with buffered output. Use `python -u` to use unbuffered output.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Using python to handle the timeout for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`serial.tools.miniterm` is a rather special tool not simply using `stdout` for output. It's a terminal emulation with special features (using [`termios`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html)) . Putting such an application in background you won't see any output.

You have two options:

- Handle timeout via python as you've done
- Don't use `miniterm`. Just printing what`s received via serial is easy.